# PostgreSQL copy command ERROR: Invalid exponent, Value 'e', Pos 187, Type: Decimal

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a parquet file in AWS S3 and I am trying to copy its data into a Redshift table. I created this table by crawling the parquet file in AWS Glue to generate the table DDL

```
COPY table_name FROM 's3://bucket/folder/file_name.parquet'
credentials 'aws_iam_role=...'
NULL AS 'NULL'
EMPTYASNULL
delimiter ','
region 'region_name'
IGNOREHEADER 1;
```

I was getting the following error: `ERROR:Invalid digit, Value '.', Pos 0, Type: Double`
Then I changed the data type from double to numeric and now I am getting this error: `ERROR:Invalid exponent, Value 'e', Pos 187, Type: Decimal`

The table has text, numeric and bigint column data types, but I do not know what column is causing this error. I don't understand the meaning of this error message. I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: You'll have to find the offending row.

Answer (score 1):

When copying data from a parquet file into a table you need to specify the format.
`FORMAT AS PARQUET` :

```
COPY table_name FROM 's3://bucket/folder/file_name.parquet'
credentials 'aws_iam_role=...'
FORMAT AS PARQUET;
```

Parquet files store data in a different way as .csv files do.

This is a field value I get when I use pandas `pd.read_parquet('path/file.parquet', engine='fastparquet')` to read the parquet file: `439.0`
And this is the same value I was trying to insert into the table: `?..7.????.17?.?..v???A????`

I was obiously getting many errors when trying to insert this into a column with datatype double precision.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the data in the parquet file is stored in an exponent format.  For example the number 123 can be represented as 1.23e2 (1.32 X 10^2).  I expect Redshift is not understanding this format.

If I am right you can COPY the file into Redshift with this column as a varchar and then cast it to the desired data type.